# Internal constructor with generics and `InternalsVisibleTo`

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core, roslyn

Is it possible to have a class with an internal parameterless constructor that can be used with generics when using the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute? I know you can use factory methods or reflection etc... to do this, but it would be nice not to use those methods.

If this is not possible, is this by design? If so, why?

Take the following code:

**Class Library**

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("testapp")]

namespace Test
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        internal MyClass()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**Application**

```
namespace Test
{
    public class GenericClass<T> where T: new()
    {
        // Compiles fine due to the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute
        MyClass c = new MyClass();

        T t = new T();
    }

    public class ConsumerClass
    {
        // gives the error: 'MyClass' must be a non-abstract type with a public
        // parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the
        // generic type or method 'GenericClass<T>'
        GenericClass<MyClass> g;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you get the "'MyClass' must be a non-abstract type..." error on exactly that line, and not on `GenericClass<MyClass>`?

Comment: @canton7 I did that for clarity, but I guess it wasn't that clear, so changed the location of the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This certainly doesn't violate anything in the CLR. 
So I took a [dive into Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/e76876d121a776ff4b8c1f26e2e521088682199c/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Symbols/ConstraintsHelper.cs#L969) which shows the constraint as:

```
        if (typeParameter.HasConstructorConstraint && !SatisfiesConstructorConstraint(typeArgument.Type))
        {
            // this must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor                 
            return false;
        }
```

where `SatisfiesConstructorConstraint` just checks

```
HasPublicParameterlessConstructor((NamedTypeSymbol)typeArgument) && !typeArgument.IsAbstract;
```

and as you'd expect, `HasPublicParameterlessConstructor` just checks if any constructor is:

```
constructor.DeclaredAccessibility == Accessibility.Public;
```

They've not implemented any leeway for the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute. The type information is available though. Maybe open an issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. From [the spec](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029), section 4.4.4:

> If the constraint is the constructor constraint `new()`, the type A must not be abstract and must have a public parameterless constructor. This is satisfied if one of the following is true:
>
> - A is a value type, since all value types have a public default constructor (§4.1.2).
> - A is a type parameter having the constructor constraint (§10.1.5).
> - A is a type parameter having the value type constraint (§10.1.5).
> - A is a class that is not abstract and **contains an explicitly declared public constructor with no parameters**.
> - A is not abstract and has a default constructor (§10.11.4).

As for *why* this is the design, it's probably just because nobody designed it to work with InternalsVisibleToAttribute. That would have required extra work specifying, implementing and testing the feature, and I suspect either nobody thought of it, or it was deemed not worth the effort.